# Android, Java: Is it possible to have multiple layouts on a drag-able list?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have multiple classes with different layouts which I call them **Widgets** in my app (this is a whole different thing from so called "Android Widgets"). I want to put instances of these classes beside each other in an activity called **Dashboard**. So users can change the place and settings of these widgets inside the dashboard and etc... .

I tried to use **[DragListView](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView)** library, but the problem is each list mush have one layout AFAIK.

Any suggestions?